# Spring SchedukedTask strat only once

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I am using spring3.2 for `taskscheduling`. I am currently run the job for every 3 hours
what i am looking is start the cron job initally when application starts but never again.

and how would i stop the scheduled task if i don't need means?

I am new to the Spring task scheduling. Please help me?

Comment: why you schedule it if you want to run it once

Comment: then how can i run it in spring mvc

Comment: if u want a separate thread for this then u can use @Async in spring,and you can call this on bean creation time //@postconstruct do the same